# PouchDB force update

Tags: pouchdb

The below code adds a new document perfectly; but it won't update because of conflict. I would like to update the document on conflict.

```
var db = new PouchDB('phppos');

var new_customer = {'_id': 'customer_'+customer.person_id,type: 'customer',first_name: customer.first_name,last_name:customer.last_name,account_number:customer.account_number,person_id:customer.person_id};

//I would like to make this document update if it exists without getting a conflict
db.put(new_customer,{force: true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first use `customer_'+customer.person_id` as identifier to attempt to get the customer record. If found, copy the `_rev` attribute into the replacement record and then save it to the database.

The `_rev` (revision number) attribute is PouchDb's mechanism for keeping track of changes in a controlled way, so that consistency can be achieved across all copies of your database. Programming for PouchDb requires constant awareness of the ways that the revision number might be altered elsewhere and replicated to other database copies.